# MSSQL MAX returns all results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have tried the following query to return the highest P.Maxvalue for each ME.Name from the last day between 06:00 and 18:00:

```
SELECT MAX(P.MaxValue) AS Value,P.DateTime,ME.Name AS ID
FROM            vManagedEntity AS ME INNER JOIN
                     Perf.vPerfHourly AS P ON ME.ManagedEntityRowId = P.ManagedEntityRowId INNER JOIN
                     vPerformanceRuleInstance AS PRI ON P.PerformanceRuleInstanceRowId = PRI.PerformanceRuleInstanceRowId INNER JOIN
                     vPerformanceRule AS PR ON PRI.RuleRowId = PR.RuleRowId
WHERE        (ME.ManagedEntityTypeRowId = 2546) AND (pr.ObjectName = 'VMGuest-cpu') AND (pr.CounterName LIKE 'cpuUsageMHz') AND (CAST(p.DateTime as time) >= '06:00:00' AND CAST(p.DateTime as time) <='18:00:00') AND  (p.DateTime > DATEADD(day, - 1, getutcdate())) 
group by ME.Name,P.DateTime
ORDER by id
```

but it seems to return each MaxValue for each ID instead of the highest?

like:

```
Value   DateTime    ID
55  2018-02-19 12:00:00.000 bob:vm-100736
51  2018-02-19 13:00:00.000 bob:vm-100736
53  2018-02-19 14:00:00.000 bob:vm-100736
52  2018-02-19 15:00:00.000 bob:vm-100736
52  2018-02-19 16:00:00.000 bob:vm-100736
51  2018-02-19 17:00:00.000 bob:vm-100736
54  2018-02-19 18:00:00.000 bob:vm-100736
51  2018-02-20 06:00:00.000 bob:vm-100736
51  2018-02-20 07:00:00.000 bob:vm-100736
53  2018-02-20 08:00:00.000 bob:vm-100736
52  2018-02-20 09:00:00.000 bob:vm-100736
78  2018-02-19 12:00:00.000 bob:vm-101
82  2018-02-19 13:00:00.000 bob:vm-101
79  2018-02-19 14:00:00.000 bob:vm-101
78  2018-02-19 15:00:00.000 bob:vm-101
79  2018-02-19 16:00:00.000 bob:vm-101
77  2018-02-19 17:00:00.000 bob:vm-101
82  2018-02-19 18:00:00.000 bob:vm-101
82  2018-02-20 06:00:00.000 bob:vm-101
79  2018-02-20 07:00:00.000 bob:vm-101
81  2018-02-20 08:00:00.000 bob:vm-101
82  2018-02-20 09:00:00.000 bob:vm-101
155 2018-02-19 12:00:00.000 bob:vm-104432
```

there is one value per hour for each id hence twelve results for each id

does MAX not work in this way i want ?

Thanks

expected view like this :

```
Value   DateTime    ID
55  2018-02-19 12:00:00.000 bob:vm-100736
82  2018-02-19 13:00:00.000 bob:vm-101
etc
```

Comment: That's because youre using group by`P.DateTime`. you need cast(P.DateTime as date)`

Comment: YOu're gettingthe max value for your groups, which in this case is `ME.Name` and `P.DateTime`. SQL Server is doing exactly as you've asked. What are you expecting as your output? Also, when you say "ID" what are you referring to. in your query, `ID` is an alias for `ME.Name`; thus stating "I want the Max value for ME.Name" and "I want to Max value for ID" means exactly the same thing.

Comment: Your query asks for the MAX per name and *datetime*, not per name. Why did you put `p.DateTime` in the GROUP BY and `SELECT` clauses if you don't want it? What do you want the results to look like?

Comment: You need to edit your question and show us some sample data and show us the result you want from that. Maybe that will help us understand better what you need

Comment: @Larnu yes i see what you are saying, i have asked SQL for the max value for the three fields (value,date,id) so SQL is returning that, If i remove the date from the select then i am returned the individual max value per id, but i would like the date in the results somehow still ( if i expanded the WHERE to 7 days for example i would like 7 max results per id ( one for each day ) if possible. I have added the expected result to the question now

Comment: So, are you actually looking for the row that contains the highest value for Value for that date and time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `group by` on datetime and id, you'll get all datetimes and all ids, it's that simple.

If you don't need exact time, you can group by date only:

```
SELECT MAX(P.MaxValue) AS Value, cast(P.DateTime as date) as dat, ME.Name AS ID
...
group by ME.Name, cast(P.DateTime as date)
```

Or if you do, you may use [not exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms188336(v=sql.110).aspx) clause instead of `group by`.